# Will gradient back propagate through multiple dynamic_rnn?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use two stacking `dynamic_rnn` in my model, which means that the `initial_state` of the second `dynamic_rnn` is the `final_state` output by the first `dynamic_rnn`. My loss function is calculated only based on the `output` of the second `dynamic_rnn`. My question is that would the gradient be back propagated to the first `dynamic_rnn`?

You may ask me why I verbosely use two `dynamic_rnn` instead of one. The answer is that for my problem, most input sequences are totally identical except the last step. So I just run `dynamic_rnn` once for the common part of all these input sequences for the purpose of saving time and feed the `final_state` to another `dynamic_rnn` which accepts the distinct and last input elements.

Suppose that we have 3 sequences with length 10. All these sequences are identical except the last step (the 10th element). The simplified code:

```
cell = BasicRNNCell()
# the first dynamic_rnn which handles the common part
first_outputs, first_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    cell=cell,
    dtype=tf.float32,
    sequence_length=[9], # only one sample with length 9
    inputs=identical_input # input with shape (1, 9, input_element_dim)
)
# tile the first_states to accommodate next dynamic_rnn
# first_states is transformed from shape (1, hidden_state_dim) to (3, hidden_state_dim)
first_states = tf.reshape(tf.tile(first_states, [1, 3]), [3, hidden_state_dim]) 
# the second dynamic_rnn which handles the distinct last element
second_outputs, second_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    initial_state=first_states,
    cell=cell,
    dtype=tf.float32,
    sequence_length=[1, 1, 1], # 3 samples with only one element
    inputs=distinct_input # input with shape (3, 1, input_element_dim)
)
# calculate loss based on second_outputs
loss = some_loss_function(second_outputs, groud_truth)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should.  If you're seeing problems, please describe the error you're getting in a little more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Professor Andersen! I have manually checked the values of the parameters of the RNN at different epochs, and they do change. So the gradient must have been back propagated through multiple `dynamic_rnn`.